# DJANGO-STORAGES, PARAMIKO: connection failure for global connection

Tags: ftp, sftp, paramiko, ftp-client, python-django-storages

I have a strange problem using the SFTP-API from django-storages(https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages). I am trying to use it in order to fetch media-files, which are stored on a different server and thus needed to create a Proxy for SFTP Downloads, since plain Django just sends GET-requests to the `MEDIA_ROOT`. I figured that Middleware provides a good hook:

```
import mimetypes

from storages.backends.sftpstorage import SFTPStorage
from django.http import HttpResponse



from storages.backends.sftpstorage import SFTPStorage

class SFTPMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response


    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        try:
            path = request.get_full_path()
            SFTP = SFTPStorage()  # <- this is where the magic happens

            if SFTP.exists(path):
                file = SFTP._read(path)

                type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(path)  
                response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=type)
                response['Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename="{filename}"'.format(filename=path)
        except PermissionError:
            pass

        return response
```

which works fine, but obviously it opens a new connection every time a website call is issued which I don't want (it also crashes after 3 reloads or something, I think it has to many parallel connections by then). So I tried just opening one connection to the Server via SFTP by moving the `SFTP = SFTPStorage()`-initialization into the `__init__()`-method which is just called once:

```
import mimetypes

from storages.backends.sftpstorage import SFTPStorage
from django.http import HttpResponse


from storages.backends.sftpstorage import SFTPStorage


class SFTPMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.SFTP = SFTPStorage() # <- this is where the magic happens


    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        try:
            path = request.get_full_path()


            if self.SFTP.exists(path):
                file = self.SFTP._read(path)

                type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(path)  
                response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=type)
                response['Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename="{filename}"'.format(filename=path)
        except PermissionError:
            pass

        return response
```

But this implementation doesn't seem to work, the program is stuck either before the `SFTP.exists()` or after the `SFTP._read()` methods.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this problem? Or does anybody even have a better idea as to how to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Kingrimursel

Comment: You need to use `paramiko.transport` on running your web application. It has a session for every connection will become safe. You need login only when you django run.

Comment: Hi @BarışŞenyerli , thanks for the answert. Could you maybe ellaborate a little bit or link a tutorial on what exactly to do? Thanks!

Comment: did you resolve?